# How to convert the following JSON array into IDictionary<string, object>?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Following is the serialized JSON array I want to convert to `IDictionary`

```
[
  {
    "8475": 25532
  },
  {
    "243": 521
  },
  {
    "3778": 15891
  },
  {
    "3733": 15713
  }
]
```

When I tried to use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>((string)jarray);
```

I got an error saying:

> Cannot cast 'jarray' (which has an actual type of 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray') to 'string'

The JSON deserializer requires only a string.

Comment: An array in brackets? Is this valid JSON?

Comment: If you already have a `JArray` instance, then why would you convert to a string to convert back to some JSON.NET type to convert to an `IDictionary`? (And you cannot deserialise to an interface, it has to be to a concrete type.)

Comment: why are you not calling the `ToString()` method on jarray if you really want a string out of it?

Comment: Your JSON string is invalid. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Mario, when i tried the following, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(jarray.ToString()); i got message- Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you already have the `JArray`, all you have to do is convert it to a dictionary I guess.

Roughly something like this:

```
IDictionary<string,object> dict = jarray.ToDictionary(k=>((JObject)k).Properties().First().Name, v=> v.Values().First().Value<object>());
```

[Check this for complete code with an example](http://dotnetfiddle.net/rjMjuR)

I think there might be a better way to convert it to a dictionary though. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 2):

the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` Method takes a JSON **string**, in other words a **serialized** object.
You have a deserialized object, so you'll have to serialize it first, which is actually pointless, considering you have all the information you need right there in the `JArray` object. If you are aiming just to get the objects from the array as key value pairs, you can do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (JObject content in jarray.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
    {
        myDictionary.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To turn your `JArray` into a string, you'll need to assign the key & values of the dictionary for each element. Mario gave a very accurate approach. But there's a somewhat prettier approach as long as you know how to convert each item into your desired type. The below example is for `Dictionary<string, string>` but can be applied to any `Value` type.

```
//Dictionary<string, string>
var dict = jArray.First() //First() is only necessary if embedded in a json object
                 .Cast<JProperty>()
                 .ToDictionary(item => item.Name,
                               item => item.Value.ToString()); //can be modified for your desired type
```